# Code for php navigation menu

Tags: php, menu, navigation, hyperlink

I have a website I manage for a mens clothing store, at www.malefashionsco.com.  On the home page, if you click one of the tuxedo categories, you'll see it says "category not found".  I have created the categories on the backend of the ecommerce platform, but they do not show.  There should be a page for each of the tuxedos, also, once in the category, the left sidebar menu should have the categories listed.  An example is at

http://www.malefashionsco.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=9

Here is the code for the menu:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
<div class="box-content">
<div class="box-category">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li>
      <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo      $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php } else { ?>

      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
        <li>
          <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
          <?php } ?>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
        </li>
       <?php } ?>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

PHP is not my strong suit.  What would the code look like to put in the `<li>` to create the links?

Comment: Looking at the code I don't see anything wrong. Where does $categories come from?

Comment: eww, inline php with html

Comment: @Bot what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Growler what's right with it?

Comment: Mixing PHP and HTML != to mixing peanut butter and jelly.  It's just gross.

Comment: @cbuckley (and/or Bot)- while I agree this code looks pretty rough, perhaps you could post a link or two to a better way of doing things?

Comment: @BennyHill this could be a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689155/basic-mvc-php-structure